# Why am I getting an error with this multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to Javascript and trying to understand multi-dimensional arrays. Why does the following code work?

```
var occupied = [[],[]];
occupied[1][0] = 0;
console.log(occupied[1][0]);
```

Yet, this code does not work.

```
var occupied = [[],[]];
occupied[2][0] = 0;
console.log(occupied[2][0]);
```

It also works with occupied[0][0]. Just not anything above 1.

Comment: Arrays are 0-indexed and the length of `occupied` is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`occupied[1][0] = 0;` works because the length of `occupied` is 2. `occupied[1]` will access the second node, which is an empty array `occupied[1][0] = 0;` this will assign 0 to the first element of the second node of `occupied` array.

```js
var occupied = [
  [], // Index 0
  [], // Index 1 => occupied[1][0] will access the first item of empty array in this location
];
occupied[1][0] = 0;
console.log(occupied[1][0]);
console.log(occupied);
```

`occupied[2][0] = 0;` this will not work. works because the length of `occupied` is 2. `occupied[2]` will try to access the third node `occupied` array, which donot exist. In this case `occupied[2]` is undefined. `occupied[2][0] = 0;` will try to set 0 to zeroth index of an undefined variable, this will throw a refrence errror like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')
```

Comment: Ohhh I get it now... Thank you

Comment: @user3249 please approve this anwer, if this answers your question

Answer (score 4):

That's because you have defined only two items in your array (index 0 and index 1). So there is no index 2.

```js
//      index:   0   1
var occupied = [ [], [] ];
occupied[1][0] = 0;
// works, index 1 exists
console.log(occupied[1][0]);
// error, index 2 doesn't exist
console.log(occupied[2][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Size of your occupied array is 2 .
So the maximum index you can access is 1.
If you try to access any index above 1 it means that you are accessing undefined.

Now , as line 2 is,
occupied[2][0] = 0 ;
here occupied[2][0] is undefined and you cannot store anything inside undefined , which is causing you an error :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I create a multidimensional array that is of size [3][3] for example.

Comment: you can increase the size of array "occupied" by pushing an array into it .
for example , occupied = [ [ ] ];
                      occupied.push( [ ] ); // this increases the size of occupied array .